# c++ List of classes without initializing them for use of static functions

Tags: c++, list, static

I may be asking this in a odd way, but I'm not sure how else to ask.

I want to have a list of classes, not objects.
This way I can call static functions without have to create the object.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?  What are you planning on doing with these classes?  What static functions are you trying to call?  Is this at compile-time or at runtime?

Comment: I want to register a list of classes to a list in a factory class.  Iterate over those classes to look for the one I need (using static methods) then instantiate it and return it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would really prefer function pointers at this point:

```
struct A
{
  void SomeFunc(int);
};

struct B
{
  void AnotherFunc(int);
};


typedef void (*Function)(int);

std::vector<Function> vec;

vec.push_back(A::SomeFunc); vec.push_back(B::AnotherFunc);

for (Function f: vec)
{
  f(2);
}
```

Note that a static function is more or less equivalent to a traditional C-function (it just got to access some more scope).

Comment: I chose this route so I didn't have to use boost and I could practice implementing function pointers.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are [boost typelists](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/list.html). I would however not recommend diving into the Boost MPL if you are not already **very** experienced with templates, and know how many of their intricacies work.

Now for a simple home-made implementation:

```
struct Null {};

template <typename Type, typename Next>
struct List
{
  typedef Type Type;
  typedef Next Next;
};

//Now you can make lists like so:
typedef List<int, List<float List<short, Null> > > MyList;
```

From there use recursive Templated implementations to call the static methods you want.

If you want more information on these kinds of techniques, you should read [Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)

Comment: There really should be more elegant solutions to these problems.

Comment: @AlexanderRafferty: 0x has variadic templates.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution you can create a list of method pointers

Answer (score 0):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/refmanual_toc.html

eg:

```
typedef vector<C1,C2,C3> types;
at_c<types,0>::type::method();
...
```

Comment: Your link isn't very helpful. Atleast explain what the're supposed to do with it.

Comment: Also, I really wouldn't recommend `using mpl::vector;` or `using namespace mpl;`. The potential for confusion with `std::vector` is just too great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking is possible, at least not in the way you think. You cannot have a variable, array, container class or any other storage of type names. So you cannot do something like

```
ListOfClasses[n]::someStaticMember(...);
```

in C++. It is impossible.