# Refer to derivative function

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, static

I have a base class and a few derivative. I have to 'register' some static function from each of them. Here is the example:

```
class Base
{
   // Some interface...
};

class Der1 : Base
{
   static void Do();
};
class Der2 : Base
{
   static void Do();
};

void processStatic()
{
   SomeFunc(Der1::Do);
   SomeFunc(Der2::Do);
}
```

As you see, `SomeFunc` receives function pointer. I want to do that automatically with each new derivative class, is it possible? Maybe, predefine static function in `Base` class and register it there. But I think it's impossible, yes?

---

Maybe, this will be more easier to understand what do I want:

```
class Der1 : Base
{
   Der1() { SomeFunc(Der1::Do); }
   static void Do();
};
class Der2 : Base
{
   Der2() { SomeFunc(Der2::Do); }
   static void Do();
};
```

Comment: What does `SomeFunc` do? Do you want it to be called every construction, like your second example, or only once, like presumed in your first example? Does it matter when? Does order matter?

Comment: Do you want to call the registration function once per class, or once per object? The first example implies the former; the second example implies the latter.

Comment: @rob-adams once per class. @gman that function put function pointer into some list which I use later.

Comment: So what does the base class have to do with it?

Comment: @gman The main idea is that each Derivative class will add it's static method into some map of function pointers.

Comment: @Ockonal: I understand, but where is `Base` necessary? Or is that just noise with respect to the question?

Comment: @gman I just thought how to do that with base class. But seems it's possible without it.

Comment: @Ockonal: Okay, so you don't need `Base`? That was just an attempt?

Comment: @gman yes :) Any way to automatically call SomeFunc with each new derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Completely replacing previous answer due to clarified requirements.

You could use the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to declare a specialized base class that does nothing more than call your registration function:

```
#include <iostream>
void SomeFunc(void(*fp)()) {
  (*fp)();
};

template <class D>
struct ExtraBass {
  ExtraBass() {
    static bool once;
    if(!once)
      SomeFunc(D::Do);
    once = true;
  }
};

struct Bass {
};

struct Drive : Bass, ExtraBass<Drive>  {
  static  void Do() { std::cout << "Drive::Do\n"; }
};

struct Deride : Bass , ExtraBass<Deride> {
  static  void Do() { std::cout << "Deride::Do\n"; }
};

int main() {
  Drive d1;
  Deride d2;
  Deride d3;
}
```

Comment: Bass -> Base. :) Though extra bass can be sweet.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy thing to do in C++, but I'm not saying it's impossible. If all you need is a list of subclass names, these answers might help:

[Somehow register my classes in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691473/c-c-somehow-register-my-classes-in-a-list/1691506#1691506)

[c++ List of classes without initializing them for use of static functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835383/c-list-of-classes-without-initializing-them-for-use-of-static-functions/4835412#4835412)

Seems either macro magic or boost mpl is your tool of choice.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it sounds impossible without some "macro magic"

Answer (score 0):

I just wondering, if you did something like

```
void SomeFunc(void (*doFunc)())
{ 
   doFunc();
}

template <class T> int Register()
{
    SomeFunc(T::Do);
    return 0;
}

template <class T> class Base
{
   static int _i;
};

template <class T> int Base<T>::_i =  Register<T>();

class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
   public:
   static void Do() {  }
};
```

Comment: `template <class T> int Base<T>::_i =  Register<T>();` That is not automatic registering I was talking about.